# XML and XSL don't display as I hope

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this file named "Spider-Man.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Spider-Man.xsl"?>

<movie>
    <title>Spider-Man</title>
    <year>2002</year>
    <genre>action</genre>
</movie>
```

and this named "Spider-Man.xsl"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
        <h1>Information on a film</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>    <xsl:value-of select="/movie/title"/>   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Year</td>
                <td>    <xsl:value-of select="/movie/year"/>    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Genre</td>
                <td>    <xsl:value-of select="/movie/genre"/>   </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open Spider-Man.xml I display all as unique text (so no `<h1>`, no `<table>`). But, if I go in console i see the code i want to display.

Why is not displayed well?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is unclear, perhaps because English is not your first language? At any rate, you can compensate for that by showing the _output you get and the output you expect_. Or, in plain English: What is your problem with this XSLT code?

Comment: When I open the xml file, the tags 'h1' and 'table' are not working. I want a table, it shows plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a border e.g. `<table border="1">` and you'll see the table's layout.

`t1` appears to display as I'd expect.

Comment: Adding the border as you suggest, now the tag 'h1' and the tag 'table' too. Before all 'tr' was on a single lane, now not...but i don't understand why..

Comment: What layout are you expecting?

Comment: With my first code written above, my "<tr>"s were on same lane. I expcted that every '<tr>' was on different lane. Changing only the 'table border', the layout is changed and now is how i expected it.